# sed replace tab ahead of specific character with line break

Tags: tabs

I know how to do this in a text editor but it shuts my computer down because I have a large file. I have tab-separated data like this all on a single line:

> XP_23947974  XM_23947974  HG12390  product=blahblah  NP_23947975  XM_23947975  HG12391  product=blahblah2

And I want to insert a line break at every either XP or NP. So, as it is tab-separated, in the text editor I was just going to do

```
Find:(\D)P_
Replace:\n\1P_
```

Giving

> XP_23947974  XM_23947974  HG12390  product=blahblah
>   NP_23947975  XM_23947975  HG12391  product=blahblah2

But I want to use sed (etc) to do that. help appreciated.

Comment: Have you googled the problem? Seems like it would be common a issue. Post some code if you are having issues with it.

Comment: I googled it a lot. But maybe I didn't use the correct combination of keywords. I didn't understand the use of the pipe which the below answer helped with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/\(XP\|NP\)/\n\1/g'
```

You can test this with:

```
echo 'XP_23947974 XM_23947974 HG12390 product=blahblah NP_23947975 XM_23947975 HG12391 product=blahblah2' | sed -e 's/\(XP\|NP\)/\n\1/g'
```

Comment: No problems, glad I could help :) Do i get an 'up' on my answer?

Comment: I don't have the "rep" to do that. I need 15. Is there another way? I'm a newb.

Comment: You can still mark it as the answer by clicking the tick next to Nick's answer.